# JavaScript "associative" array access

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative

I have a simple simulated array with two elements:

```
bowl["fruit"] = "apple";
bowl["nuts"] = "brazilian";
```

I can access the value with an event like this:

```
onclick = "testButton00_('fruit')">with `testButton00_`

function testButton00_(key){
    var t = bowl[key];
    alert("testButton00_: value = "+t);
}
```

However, whenever I try to access the array from within code with a key that is just a non-explicit string, I get *undefined*. Do I have somehow have to pass the parameter with the escaped 'key'?

Comment: What do you mean by "just a non-explicit string"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The key can be a dynamically computed string. Give an example of something you pass that doesn't work.

Given:

```
var bowl = {}; // empty object
```

You can say:

```
bowl["fruit"] = "apple";
```

Or:

```
bowl.fruit = "apple"; // NB. `fruit` is not a string variable here
```

Or even:

```
var fruit = "fruit";
bowl[fruit] = "apple"; // now it is a string variable! Note the [ ]
```

Or if you really want to:

```
bowl["f" + "r" + "u" + "i" + "t"] = "apple";
```

Those all have the same effect on the `bowl` object. And then you can use the corresponding patterns to retrieve values:

```
var value = bowl["fruit"];
var value = bowl.fruit; // fruit is a hard-coded property name
var value = bowl[fruit]; // fruit must be a variable containing the string "fruit"
var value = bowl["f" + "r" + "u" + "i" + "t"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use JSON if you don’t want to escape the key:

```
var bowl = {
  fruit: "apple",
  nuts: "brazil"
};

alert(bowl.fruit);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you. You can make sure the key is a string like this

```
if(!key) {
  return;
}
var k = String(key);
var t = bowl[k];
```

Or you can check if the key exists:

```
if(typeof(bowl[key]) !== 'undefined') {
  var t = bowk[key];
}
```

However, I don't think you have posted the non-working code?