# Add a child to a JavaScript object with a variable name

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a blank JavaScript object:

```
myObject {}
```

And I also have a variable:

```
var myChildObject = this.name.split('.')[1];
```

For the sake of an example, let's say that `myChildObject` equals "FooBar".  Now,  I want to add a child object to `myObject` with the name of "FooBar", only we can't hard code "FooBar".  We have to use the variable name `myChildObject`.

I tried this:

```
myObject.appendChild(myChildObject);
```

That doesn't work.

The goal is this:

```
{  
   "myObject":{  
      "FooBar":{  
         "thing1":25,
         "thing2":6
      },
      .....
}
```

But I need to build the entire thing dynamically, without the names (other than the root) being known ahead of time.

Comment: `"FooBar"` is a string though, not an object.

Comment: myObject[myChildObject] = ?;

Comment: Right @Madara.  I want to add a new object with the name of "FoBar"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript "associative" array access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524413/javascript-associative-array-access)

Comment: JavaScript object has key value pair. What do you want as the key for *FooBar*

Comment: Your goal is not valid JavaScript. Objects need a key and a value. Do you want an array? `{MyObject: ["FooBar"]}`?

Comment: @dave -- I don't see how my question and that question are even close to the same thing.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston note that your "goal" is invalid JS. What value does "FooBar" map to?

Comment: See my edit to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object is a "key value" type of thing, a little bit like a Map in Java. have you tried something like this:

```
let myObject = {};
let myChildObject = "fooBar";
myObject[myChildObject] = {};
```

This way you have a "fooBar" key for your Object... now you have to decide what you want the value to be for that key.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObject = {};
var myChildObject = this.name.split('.')[1];
myObject[myChildObject] ={  
     "thing1":25,
     "thing2":6
  };
```

Comment: Thank you, but, the thing is, FooBar can not be hard coded. I don't know the name of FooBar ahead of time, so it MUST be a variable

Comment: Ok, we are on to something now!  Lemme play with this and I'll BRB.

Answer (score 1):

Objects can only have key value pair. You cannot use one without other. If you don't want to assign a value then simply give undefined. If you don't know the name of the property then you can simply use the array type notation for an object "[]". Refer to code below

```
var myObject = {};
var myChildObject = this.name.split('.')[1];

myObject[myChildObject] = undefined;

console.log(myObject.hasOwnProperty(myChildObject)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

```
for(var key in myChildObject) {
  myObject[key] = myChildObject[key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea what your question means but myObject["foobar"] might be what you are looking for