# How to convert numbers into text Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am currently learning JS but I thought I'd give it a shot and create this conversion. I don't know what I am doing wrong and I'd appreciate if anyone can guide me.

```
    const box = prompt('Enter Number');

function numberName(n){
  
  const lNumbers = ["","Zero",'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']

if (n==0){
  const a = lNumbers.indexOf("Zero");
  console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what is it actually doing that is incorrect?  What are you entering as input, and what is the expected result?

Comment: Basically put a number which outputs it in text. So, 1 will give one and so on... I dont know what else to do to achieve that. I'm new to JS

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for. Simply use bracket notation to get the array item you are looking for by index.

```js
const wordifyNum = num => ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four"][num];

wordifyNum(0); // -> "Zero"
wordifyNum(1); // -> "One"
wordifyNum(2); // -> "Two"
wordifyNum(3); // -> "Three"
wordifyNum(4); // -> "Four"
```

For a more robust example that works all the way up to 999 dynamically, check out [wordify.js](https://gist.github.com/NinaScholz/43fa92a6095dc4d96c73) by Nina Scholz.

Comment: What do i do after that ? I'm confused

Comment: This works as is. This function converts and returns the desired number as a word. In order to log its result to the console, do this: `console.log(wordifyNum(4))`, which will log `"four"` to the console. Just add as many number words as you need to support in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but put yourself in the wrong direction

```
const a = lNumbers.indexOf("Zero");
```

This is incorrect: Why would you want to know the position of a hardcoded string 'Zero'?

Instead, you want to use the value of `box` and access the lNumbers by key. You can see [this answer and then the 2nd codeblock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524432/2519416)<sup>1</sup>. They use a hardcoded `"fruit"`, but you have something else to put there ;)

<sub><sup>1</sup> Actually, the forth is what you are looking for, but because the variable name and its value are the same, it could be a little confusing</sub>

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by the value of box? Your solution is a little confusing to me

Comment: @amir You have a variable called `box`.  It contains a value.